# how to validate if API call is being made from an valid source?

Tags: security, architecture, encryption-asymmetric

My App has few endpoints open to the public:

```
1. API to register a Source  ( Source also provides JWKS URL) 
2. API to send data (Data is Sent with Private Key and KEY ID)
```

Happy Path:

```
 1. Subscriber registers as a source
 2. Subscriber app sends data |
 3. My App parses data and validates
```

Not a Happy Path:

```
 1. Malicious Actor registers as a source 
 2. Malicious Actor sends data 
 3. My App parses data and validates
```

App performs validation, but data shared is meaning less and I should have stopped before Step 3.

I understand this is more of system abuse rather than a security issue. A few ways to handle this are API Rate limiting, Validating Header, Checking Referer, etc. But still feels insufficient.

I have to make APIs public for now so sources can register themselves and share data.
Looking for design related decisions, suggestions and corrections.